# Java Garbage Collection Strategy

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-6

I'm looking for a technique to find out the Garbage Collection (GC) strategy (collector) the Java VM is using at a given point of time. (Later on, I'd like it to correctly reflect the strategy that I choose, say `XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`.)

`verbose:gc` (in its basic form) does not help as it just shows me what all it did with each *generation*. Is there any other flag I can set to make it spit out the GC strategy being utilized?

JDK version is 1.6_21

Comment: I added another tidbit on `jinfo.exe` to my answer.

Comment: Note that this is highly vendor dependent.

Comment: The default (Parallel) GC strategy is always the same.  It will be Conccurent Mark Sweep or G1 only if this has been specificed on the command line.  Perhaps you could explain, why you don't know which GC you are specifying...

Comment: @Peter, how can we be sure the default is always parallel? Is there a way to check that? And with the ergonomics in place, is that always true?

Comment: If you need to use a specific GC strategy, you should specify it. Don't leave it to chance.  Usually, it does matter.  However for Sun's Java 1.4.2 and later, the default is the Parallel GC.  See Sun's documentation.  If you use another JVM it may be a completely different GC strategy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mmmm.. you can certainly find out what strategy is being used by a certain JVM with jconsole (VM Summary) page. Not sure about influencing it, or changing it.

EDIT:
To assist you with programmatically checking and changing JVM flags of a running VM you can use the `jinfo.exe` utility in the JDK. For example to check if the ParallelGC flag is set you can run: `jinfo.exe -flag UseParallelGC <PID>`.

Comment: Yay! I think that's the answer to my woes. :)
jconsole gave me details of the form:
--
Garbage collector: 
Name = 'PS MarkSweep', Collections = 0, Total time spent = 0.000 seconds

Garbage collector: 
Name = 'PS Scavenge', Collections = 9, Total time spent = 0.028 seconds
--
And yes, it did get influenced when I set the VM args: -XX:+UseParallelGC (and overrode the default (ConcMarkSweepGC)).

Thanks!

Comment: Just that, I'm not able to figure the default strategy VM is using (that is, if I don't explicitly pass a VM arg for GC). jconsole summary shows me this:
Garbage collector: 
Name = 'Copy', Collections = 319, Total time spent = 1.188 seconds
Garbage collector: 
Name = 'MarkSweepCompact', Collections = 5, Total time spent = 0.454 seconds

But when I use jinfo.exe -flag UseConcMarkSweepGC <pid>
I gives me a negative flag (indicating that its not being used). Anyway, I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get this information at runtime in the application that is running on the JVM, then you can use the [GarbageCollectorMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()):

```
List<GarbageCollectorMXBean> gcs =
  ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans();
for (GarbageCollectorMXBean gc : gcs) {
  System.out.println(gc.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try jinfo utility provided with JDK. Provide the JVM process PID to this utility and it will display you all the generic argument passed to this JVM process. Following is the URL for the same :

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jinfo.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Again, GC behavior can be influenced, but not predicted.

Comment: I'm interesting in finding out what all it got influenced by. :)